# Can we stop asteroids from hitting the earth using a laser?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, laser, estimation, asteroids

[This](https://youtu.be/4Wrc4fHSCpw) new video from Veritasium talks about the probabilities of an asteroid hitting the earth and the destructions it can cause.

At last they talk about **how can we prevent an asteroid from colliding with earth** and Proff. Dave Jewitt mentions that *although we can take the help of **lasers to destroy it** but he mentions that we don't have such a powerful laser*. Then he mentions that *we can cover the asteroid with a good reflective material and can take the help of photons from the sun*.

But I think we don't need to have a powerful laser at all.

---

Suppose we somehow manage to cover the asteroid with a good reflective and now we use a laser of maximum power (which we can handle) and shine it on the asteroid. The photons strike the asteroid and gets deflected and thus the asteroid feels a force for the time the laser is pointed on it but **we can re - reflect that reflected beam and point it again on the asteroid and can continue this process of re - reflection multiple times**. I know there will be some loss of energy during the multiple reflections but...

Can we use this technique to get rid of upcoming asteroids? Or am I missing some informations of asteroid impact?

**Note** : Both the laser pointer and the other reflecting surface is in outer space near to earth and not on the earth's surface.

Hope it doesn't need any image to show above texts. If it does , please comment below.

Comment: [Using the antimatter to power an x-ray laser, the travelers intend to deflect asteroid Helios 685](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelers_(TV_series)#Introduced_in_season_1) I watched it too, an amazing TV show.

Comment: I you can reach the asteroid and can cover it with a good reflective, why not use it to create a small thrust to change it's course, such that it doesn't hit earth? Isn't that currently the most feasible approach?

Comment: If you can visit the asteroid for the purpose of covering it with a reflective material, would it not be easier to "visit" it with a kinetic projectile that will deliver a great wallop of impulse and change the trajectory of the thing when it hits?

Comment: @Solomon Slow Proff. Dave Jewitt mentioned about it and said that it is not much helpful ..

Comment: @SolomonSlow a couple square kilometers of aluminum foil is much lighter, and thus easier to deliver than a heavy kinetic projectile.  The aluminum foil can also provide an effectively limitless change momentum; if you want to change it more, just shine more lasers on it for longer.  Whereas the kinetic projectile is one and done.  The aluminum foil would also make the asteroid easier to track.

Comment: Actually, it is not necessary for it to reflect the light. If the asteroid absorbs the laser- (or sun-)light, it will heat up on the that side, emit thermal radiation which has a similar effect: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crookes_radiometer see explanation for the force.

Comment: Is this laser in space or is it based on the Earth? It'd have to be pretty large to compete with the power of the Sun shining on several square kilometres of asteroid surface.

Comment: @PM 2Ring but the problem with sun's photon is that we can't adjust its positioning or direction of hitting. It can even push the asteroid more towards us. Btw assume both to be in space.

Comment: Ok, you should edit that info into your question. And maybe mention how you intend to power this ginormous laser. ;) Although we can't adjust the direction of the sunlight we can (presumably) adjust the reflectiveness of the reflective stuff we put on the asteroid.

Comment: If the laser is space based, it will push itself even harder in the opposite direction than the asteroid. Assummig that it is not as heavy, it will basically be a spaceship with laser propulsion.

Comment: @Cream but we can cope with the recoil using rockets for both laser and other reflectors.

Comment: "I know there will be some loss of energy during the multiple reflections" This will be quite the understatement.  Even with [retroreflectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroreflector) you have substantial losses.  Consider that we have a retroreflector on the moon. We shine megawatts at it, and the response is measured in single-digit photons.

Answer (score 2):

Effectively, you're asking:

> What is the force on two mirrors with a laser-beam being reflected
> between them?

Let's consider the case of a single photon. It impacts the asteroid. In order for it to change the direction of the asteroid, it must transfer some energy to the asteroid, moving the asteroid's mirror. This means, the reflected photon will come back with less energy. This photon will be *red-shifted*.

When it reflects against our local mirror, if we hold the mirror stationary (e.g. with thrusters or the planet itself), then all of the energy is reflected back. We could add energy to the photon by moving our mirror towards the asteroid (much like a tennis racket hitting a ball) (blue-shift).

On subsequent reflections all energy is transferred to the asteroid, and the total amount transferred is just the energy in the photon, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a calculation: a photon of energy $E=\hbar\omega$ has momentum $p=\hbar k=\hbar\omega/c=E/c$. The force on the asteroid is approximately the momentum of the number of photons that hit the asteroid per second, $F=RE/c$, so that asteroid of mass $M$ will acquire acceleration:
$$
a=\frac{F}{m}=\frac{RE}{mc}.
$$
Now you can take a typical distance from earth and an asteroid speed and calculate what power (energy per second), $W=R\hbar\omega$, we need to deflect it.